Is it safe to dispatch actions in store listener callbacks?
I have a Redux webpage with a complex UI component (a map). The component's visual state and its internal model depend on the current Redux store's state and browser state (viewport resolution, DPI, etc.). The component updates to Redux state changes via a listener that has subscribed to the Redux store.
The component's visual/internal state includes information (e.g. currently rendered map extent, which depends on the Redux state and resolution) that needs to be pushed to the store via dispatching an action ("mapExtentChanged"). In the corresponding action reducer, the information (map extent) is than combined with the current Redux state, resulting in different parts of the state being changed as well.
The map update to change Redux state is done synchronously in the corresponding Redux store listener. A dispatch, aiming to inform the Redux store about a new extent would follow synchronously right after in the same listener callback.
Is it generally fine to dispatch an action inside a store subscription listener callback?
What could go wrong? What should I do instead?


Is it generally fine to dispatch an action inside a store subscription
listener callback?

Yes, but with conditions.
See Store subscribe

You may call dispatch() from a change listener, with the following
caveats:

The listener should only call dispatch() either in response to user actions or under specific conditions (e. g. dispatching an action
when the store has a specific field). Calling dispatch() without any
conditions is technically possible, however it leads to an infinite
loop as every dispatch() call usually triggers the listener again.

The subscriptions are snapshotted just before every dispatch() call. If you subscribe or unsubscribe while the listeners are being
invoked, this will not have any effect on the dispatch() that is
currently in progress. However, the next dispatch() call, whether
nested or not, will use a more recent snapshot of the subscription
list.

The listener should not expect to see all state changes, as the state might have been updated multiple times during a nested
dispatch() before the listener is called. It is, however, guaranteed
that all subscribers registered before the dispatch() started will
be called with the latest state by the time it exits.



I think the point of most concern is #1 above, you want to ensure you are not unconditionally dispatching actions from the listener as this will likely trigger the listener again if there were any state updates. I've emphasized this in the quoted documentation. The subscription listener can call getState if any part of the Redux store is necessary to conditionally dispatch any actions.
